# problem: jQuery click event only works on first occurrence in text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
<span id="Santiago4">Santiago</span> 
<br>more html code here<br> 
<span id="Santiago4">Santiago</span>
<script>
    jQuery("#Santiago4").click(function() {alert("blabla")} );
</script>
```

My problem is that when I click on the html text on first occurence, the click event triggers the alert pops up. But when I click the second occurrence (or any other if Santiago appears a few times in the text) nothing happens.

Why is that? Why when clicking the second span element that it also has the id: Stantiago4 the function's code does not run?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot have more than one element with the same `id` attribute.

Comment: Further to Andrew's comment, if you need the same 'name' or reference for more than *one* element you should use `class` not `id`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Element ID attributes are intended to be unique. If you want to share attributes, rather use the class attribute:

```
<span class="santiago4">Santiago</span>
<br/>more html code here<br/> 
<span class="santiago4">Santiago2</span>
```

In other words, instead of `id`, use `class`. Then the jQuery would be:

```
jQuery(".santiago4").click(function() {
   alert("clicked!")
});
```

Now the click event will be bound to all HTML elements with the `class` 'santiago4', which is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

ID should be unique across the HTML elements.

You can instead assign a common classname to each of the span and the use .classname as jQuery selector.

Try this:

```
<span class="Santiago4">Santiago</span> <br/>
more html code here<br/> 
<span class="Santiago4">Santiago</span> 
<script>
    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery(".Santiago4").click(function() {
            alert("blabla")
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't have more than one element with the same Id, these need to be distinct. For the usage you are describing you need to use another selector such as a class:

```
<span class="Santiago4">Santiago</span> 
<br>more html code here<br> 
<span class="Santiago4">Santiago</span>
<script>
    jQuery(".Santiago4").click(function() {alert("blabla")} );
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change it to use a class because as Andrew said, you can't have more than one element with the same ID:

```
<span class="Santiago4">Santiago</span> 
<br>more html code here<br> 
<span class="Santiago4">Santiago</span>
<script>
    jQuery(".Santiago4").click(function() {alert("blabla"); } );
</script>
```

[Working JS Example](http://jsfiddle.net/6jH6Q/)

Answer (score 1):

They both have the same ID, which isnt' good HTML and will cause problems when trying to manipulate with jQuery. Try using the class name instead:

```
<span class="Santiago4">Santiago</span> <br>more html code here<br> <span class="Santiago4">Santiago</span> <script>jQuery(".Santiago4").click(function() {alert("blabla")} );</script>
```